# Finding the limit of $\sqrt[n]{1^{2022}+2^{2022}+...+n^{2022}}$

Tags: limits

I want to find the limit of the given series:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{1^{2022}+2^{2022}+...+n^{2022}}$$

I decided to use the squeeze theorem and made up two series, one greater and one lesser than the main one. Since $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n}=1$ we the result:

$$1 \leftarrow (\sqrt[n]{n})^{2022} \le \sqrt[n]{1^{2022}+2^{2022}+...+n^{2022}} \le (\sqrt[n]{n}) \times (\sqrt[n]{n})^{2022} \rightarrow 1$$

Since the left and right sequences limits are equal to $1$, then the main sequences limit is also equal to $1$ by the squeeze theorem. Is this solution correct?

Comment: It is ok${}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your bounds work:  in particular, for every positive integer $n$,
$$n^{2022} \le 1^{2022} + 2^{2022} + \cdots + n^{2022} \le \underbrace{n^{2022} + n^{2022} + \cdots + n^{2022}}_{n \text{ times}} = n^{2023}.$$
While a tighter lower bound can be obtained via the AM-GM inequality,
$$1^{2022} + 2^{2022} + \cdots + n^{2022} \ge n (n!)^{2022/n},$$ it doesn't actually make the problem any easier, since we would have to show $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (n!)^{1/n^2} = 1.$$